# Tensor Flow Tutorial: Why isn't my version of 'Deep MNIST for Experts' working correctly?

Tags: python, tensorflow, deep-learning, conv-neural-network, convolution

I tried to follow the tensorflow tutorial 'Deep MNIST for Experts' [1]. My program (source below) is working, but it converges very slowly and achieves a quite bad accuracy of ~90%. It should achieve about 99,2% accuracy. I compared my solution to the 'mnist_deep.py' available for download [2], which looks quite similar ... but achieves those 99,2% accuracy on the same machine (so it's not a bug in tensorflow nor anything wrong with my installation). Surprisingly, it needs much more time for the training on the same machine telling me the trained model must be different / more complex. I checked my sources and compared it to mine, reordered stuff and checked the numbers. But, I didn't find any relevant difference except for coding style. I'm new to python - so maybe it's just some simple syntax issue...

**Questions:**

- What is the difference in my version causing this problem?
- Additional: How to debug those issues in tensorflow? I saw some generated graphs of the models on the webpage... how to generate them from the source?

**My Program:**

```
import os
import tensorflow as tf

# os.environ['TF_CPP_MIN_LOG_LEVEL'] = '3'

def weight_variable(shape):
  initial = tf.truncated_normal(shape, stddev=0.1)
  return tf.Variable(initial)

def bias_variable(shape):
  initial = tf.constant(0.1, shape=shape)
  return tf.Variable(initial)

def conv2d(x, W):
  return tf.nn.conv2d(x, W, strides=[1,1,1,1], padding='SAME')

def max_pool_2x2(x):
  return tf.nn.max_pool(x, ksize=[1,2,2,1], strides=[1,2,2,1], padding='SAME')

from tensorflow.examples.tutorials.mnist import input_data



x = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, [None, 784])

# reshape
x_image = tf.reshape(x, [-1, 28, 28, 1])

# conv1
W_conv1 = weight_variable([5,5,1,32])
b_conv1 = bias_variable([32])
h_conv1 = tf.nn.relu(conv2d(x_image, W_conv1) + b_conv1)

# pool1
h_pool1 = max_pool_2x2(h_conv1)

# conv2
W_conv2 = weight_variable([5,5,32,64])
b_conv2 = bias_variable([64])
h_conv2 = tf.nn.relu(conv2d(h_pool1, W_conv2) + b_conv2)

# pool2
h_pool2 = max_pool_2x2(h_conv2)

# fcl
W_fc1 = weight_variable([7*7*64, 1024])
b_fc1 = bias_variable([1024])

h_pool2_flat = tf.reshape(h_pool2, [-1, 7*7*64])
h_fc1 = tf.nn.relu(tf.matmul(h_pool2_flat, W_fc1) + b_fc1)

# dropout
keep_prob = tf.placeholder(tf.float32)
h_fc1_drop = tf.nn.dropout(h_fc1, keep_prob)

# map 1024 features to 10 classes
W_fc2 = weight_variable([1024, 10])
b_fc2 = bias_variable([10])

y_conv = tf.matmul(h_fc1_drop, W_fc2) + b_fc2


mnist = input_data.read_data_sets("MNIST_data/", one_hot=True)
y_ = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, [None, 10])


# loss function
cross_entropy = tf.reduce_mean(
  tf.nn.softmax_cross_entropy_with_logits(labels=y_, logits=y_conv)
)

# ADAM Optimizer
train_step = tf.train.AdamOptimizer(1e-4).minimize(cross_entropy)

# accuracy
correct_prediction = tf.equal(tf.argmax(y_conv,1), tf.argmax(y_,1))
correct_prediction = tf.cast(correct_prediction, tf.float32)
accuracy = tf.reduce_mean(correct_prediction)



with tf.Session() as sess:
  sess.run(tf.global_variables_initializer())

  for i in range(20000):
    batch = mnist.train.next_batch(50)
    if i % 100 == 0:
      train_accuracy = accuracy.eval(feed_dict={
        x: batch[0], y_: batch[1], keep_prob: 1.0
        })
      print('step %d, training accuracy %g' % (i, train_accuracy))
      train_step.run(feed_dict={x: batch[0], y_:batch[1], keep_prob: 0.5})

  print('test accuracy %g' % accuracy.eval(feed_dict={
    x: mnist.test.images, y_: mnist.test.labels, keep_prob: 1.0}))
```

**OUTPUT:**

```
# python3 mnist_deep.py 
Extracting MNIST_data/train-images-idx3-ubyte.gz
Extracting MNIST_data/train-labels-idx1-ubyte.gz
Extracting MNIST_data/t10k-images-idx3-ubyte.gz
Extracting MNIST_data/t10k-labels-idx1-ubyte.gz
step 0, training accuracy 0.06
step 100, training accuracy 0.06
step 200, training accuracy 0
step 300, training accuracy 0.12
step 400, training accuracy 0.06
step 500, training accuracy 0.1
step 600, training accuracy 0.18
step 700, training accuracy 0.12
step 800, training accuracy 0.1
step 900, training accuracy 0.22
step 1000, training accuracy 0.2
[...]
```

**Version from the Webpage:**

```
# Copyright 2015 The TensorFlow Authors. All Rights Reserved.
#
# Licensed under the Apache License, Version 2.0 (the "License");
# you may not use this file except in compliance with the License.
# You may obtain a copy of the License at
#
#     http://www.apache.org/licenses/LICENSE-2.0
#
# Unless required by applicable law or agreed to in writing, software
# distributed under the License is distributed on an "AS IS" BASIS,
# WITHOUT WARRANTIES OR CONDITIONS OF ANY KIND, either express or implied.
# See the License for the specific language governing permissions and
# limitations under the License.
# ==============================================================================

"""A deep MNIST classifier using convolutional layers.

See extensive documentation at
https://www.tensorflow.org/get_started/mnist/pros
"""
# Disable linter warnings to maintain consistency with tutorial.
# pylint: disable=invalid-name
# pylint: disable=g-bad-import-order

from __future__ import absolute_import
from __future__ import division
from __future__ import print_function

import argparse
import sys
import tempfile

from tensorflow.examples.tutorials.mnist import input_data

import tensorflow as tf

FLAGS = None


def deepnn(x):
  """deepnn builds the graph for a deep net for classifying digits.

  Args:
    x: an input tensor with the dimensions (N_examples, 784), where 784 is the
    number of pixels in a standard MNIST image.

  Returns:
    A tuple (y, keep_prob). y is a tensor of shape (N_examples, 10), with values
    equal to the logits of classifying the digit into one of 10 classes (the
    digits 0-9). keep_prob is a scalar placeholder for the probability of
    dropout.
  """
  # Reshape to use within a convolutional neural net.
  # Last dimension is for "features" - there is only one here, since images are
  # grayscale -- it would be 3 for an RGB image, 4 for RGBA, etc.
  with tf.name_scope('reshape'):
    x_image = tf.reshape(x, [-1, 28, 28, 1])

  # First convolutional layer - maps one grayscale image to 32 feature maps.
  with tf.name_scope('conv1'):
    W_conv1 = weight_variable([5, 5, 1, 32])
    b_conv1 = bias_variable([32])
    h_conv1 = tf.nn.relu(conv2d(x_image, W_conv1) + b_conv1)

  # Pooling layer - downsamples by 2X.
  with tf.name_scope('pool1'):
    h_pool1 = max_pool_2x2(h_conv1)

  # Second convolutional layer -- maps 32 feature maps to 64.
  with tf.name_scope('conv2'):
    W_conv2 = weight_variable([5, 5, 32, 64])
    b_conv2 = bias_variable([64])
    h_conv2 = tf.nn.relu(conv2d(h_pool1, W_conv2) + b_conv2)

  # Second pooling layer.
  with tf.name_scope('pool2'):
    h_pool2 = max_pool_2x2(h_conv2)

  # Fully connected layer 1 -- after 2 round of downsampling, our 28x28 image
  # is down to 7x7x64 feature maps -- maps this to 1024 features.
  with tf.name_scope('fc1'):
    W_fc1 = weight_variable([7 * 7 * 64, 1024])
    b_fc1 = bias_variable([1024])

    h_pool2_flat = tf.reshape(h_pool2, [-1, 7*7*64])
    h_fc1 = tf.nn.relu(tf.matmul(h_pool2_flat, W_fc1) + b_fc1)

  # Dropout - controls the complexity of the model, prevents co-adaptation of
  # features.
  with tf.name_scope('dropout'):
    keep_prob = tf.placeholder(tf.float32)
    h_fc1_drop = tf.nn.dropout(h_fc1, keep_prob)

  # Map the 1024 features to 10 classes, one for each digit
  with tf.name_scope('fc2'):
    W_fc2 = weight_variable([1024, 10])
    b_fc2 = bias_variable([10])

    y_conv = tf.matmul(h_fc1_drop, W_fc2) + b_fc2
  return y_conv, keep_prob


def conv2d(x, W):
  """conv2d returns a 2d convolution layer with full stride."""
  return tf.nn.conv2d(x, W, strides=[1, 1, 1, 1], padding='SAME')


def max_pool_2x2(x):
  """max_pool_2x2 downsamples a feature map by 2X."""
  return tf.nn.max_pool(x, ksize=[1, 2, 2, 1],
                        strides=[1, 2, 2, 1], padding='SAME')


def weight_variable(shape):
  """weight_variable generates a weight variable of a given shape."""
  initial = tf.truncated_normal(shape, stddev=0.1)
  return tf.Variable(initial)


def bias_variable(shape):
  """bias_variable generates a bias variable of a given shape."""
  initial = tf.constant(0.1, shape=shape)
  return tf.Variable(initial)


def main(_):
  # Import data
  mnist = input_data.read_data_sets(FLAGS.data_dir, one_hot=True)

  # Create the model
  x = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, [None, 784])

  # Define loss and optimizer
  y_ = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, [None, 10])

  # Build the graph for the deep net
  y_conv, keep_prob = deepnn(x)

  with tf.name_scope('loss'):
    cross_entropy = tf.nn.softmax_cross_entropy_with_logits(labels=y_,
                                                            logits=y_conv)
  cross_entropy = tf.reduce_mean(cross_entropy)

  with tf.name_scope('adam_optimizer'):
    train_step = tf.train.AdamOptimizer(1e-4).minimize(cross_entropy)

  with tf.name_scope('accuracy'):
    correct_prediction = tf.equal(tf.argmax(y_conv, 1), tf.argmax(y_, 1))
    correct_prediction = tf.cast(correct_prediction, tf.float32)
  accuracy = tf.reduce_mean(correct_prediction)

  graph_location = tempfile.mkdtemp()
  print('Saving graph to: %s' % graph_location)
  train_writer = tf.summary.FileWriter(graph_location)
  train_writer.add_graph(tf.get_default_graph())

  with tf.Session() as sess:
    sess.run(tf.global_variables_initializer())
    for i in range(20000):
      batch = mnist.train.next_batch(50)
      if i % 100 == 0:
        train_accuracy = accuracy.eval(feed_dict={
            x: batch[0], y_: batch[1], keep_prob: 1.0})
        print('step %d, training accuracy %g' % (i, train_accuracy))
      train_step.run(feed_dict={x: batch[0], y_: batch[1], keep_prob: 0.5})

    print('test accuracy %g' % accuracy.eval(feed_dict={
        x: mnist.test.images, y_: mnist.test.labels, keep_prob: 1.0}))

if __name__ == '__main__':
  parser = argparse.ArgumentParser()
  parser.add_argument('--data_dir', type=str,
                      default='/tmp/tensorflow/mnist/input_data',
                      help='Directory for storing input data')
  FLAGS, unparsed = parser.parse_known_args()
  tf.app.run(main=main, argv=[sys.argv[0]] + unparsed)
```

**OUTPUT:**

```
# python3 mnist_deep.py 
Successfully downloaded train-images-idx3-ubyte.gz 9912422 bytes.
Extracting /tmp/tensorflow/mnist/input_data/train-images-idx3-ubyte.gz
Successfully downloaded train-labels-idx1-ubyte.gz 28881 bytes.
Extracting /tmp/tensorflow/mnist/input_data/train-labels-idx1-ubyte.gz
Successfully downloaded t10k-images-idx3-ubyte.gz 1648877 bytes.
Extracting /tmp/tensorflow/mnist/input_data/t10k-images-idx3-ubyte.gz
Successfully downloaded t10k-labels-idx1-ubyte.gz 4542 bytes.
Extracting /tmp/tensorflow/mnist/input_data/t10k-labels-idx1-ubyte.gz
Saving graph to: /tmp/tmpw8uaz0vs
step 0, training accuracy 0.12
step 100, training accuracy 0.64
step 200, training accuracy 0.86
step 300, training accuracy 0.94
step 400, training accuracy 0.94
[...]
```

**Links**

[1] https://www.tensorflow.org/get_started/mnist/pros

[2] https://www.github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/r1.3/tensorflow/examples/tutorials/mnist/mnist_deep.py

Comment: You can use Tensorboard to generate a visualization of each of the graphs: https://www.tensorflow.org/get_started/graph_viz

Comment: One possible reason: `train_step.run(feed_dict={x: batch[0], y_:batch[1], keep_prob: 0.5})` should be outside the `if i%100` statement

Comment: THANKS! That's the solution! A dumb python-noob-bug!^^ I just corrected this... and it's working! YEAH! It's reaching ~98% accuracy at 500 learning steps...

Comment: @Gerges Dib: would you please post this as an answer, so I can accept it and the question is visibly answered to the others...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

#### Question 1

Possible reason for poor results: `train_step.run(feed_dict={x: batch[0], y_:batch[1], keep_prob: 0.5})` should be outside the `if i%100` statement.

#### Question 2

To answer you second question, the graphs are generated by tensorboard (as mentioned by @JoshVarty). To visualize your graph, you need to write it to a file. Add the following somewhere before running the session and after defining the complete graph:

```
file_writer = tf.summary.FileWriter(".", tf.get_default_graph())
```

Then start tensorboard server in the terminal from your current path `tensorboard --logdir="."`, and you can open it from your browser with default port 6006 and the graph will appear after you run the script.